# The string is missing the terminator: ". while using powershell script in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using following powershell script in c# code:

```
Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
                runSpace.Open();
                string script = @"
                            $Session = New-Object -ComObject 'Microsoft.Update.Session'
                            $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
                            $historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
                           $UpdateHistory = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount)
                           $KBs = @()
                    foreach ($Update in $UpdateHistory) { 
                        [regex]::match($Update.Title,'(KB[0-9]{6,7})').value | Where-Object {$_ -ne ""} | foreach { 
                    $KB = New-Object -TypeName PSObject 
                    $KB | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name KB -Value $_ 
                    $KB | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Title -Value $Update.Title  
                    $KB | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $Update.Description
                    $KB | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $Update.Date    
                    $KBs += $KB
                } 
            } 
               $KBs | Select Title,KB,Date";


                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
                Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

The script runs fine in powershell. But while using it in c# code ,it returns the mentioned error. I have gone through various  related posts available in google, but no luck till now.

Comment: `Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())` - Don't you feel you have a redundant bracket here?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo mistake from my side. I have updated the post.

Comment: `""` --> `""""`

Comment: Your [here string](http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/q-what-here-string-windows-powershell) is not corrextly terminated with a `"@` at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @iRon C# verbatim string terminated with single `"` at any position in line.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks. your trick did the job.